# Why does the compiler think a std::string& is passed not a std:string

Tags: c++, string

My Question is why in `processSymbol(const string, enumDataType)` does the compiler think I am passing a std::string&. I used `processSymbol(const string, enumDataType)` earlier in my code and work just as intended, but in this function I am getting this erro

```
error: call of overloaded 'processSymbol(std::string&, symsErrorCode&)' is ambiguous|
note: candidates are:
note: void processSymbol(std::string, symsErrorCode&)|
note: void processSymbol(std::string, symsErrorCode)|
```

Here is the function I am wondering about.

```
void processSearchForSymbols(ifstream & inSyms, BST & symTable){
   symsErrorCode symsError;
   string symbol;
   while(inSyms >> symbol){
       symsError = NO_ERROR;
       processSymbol(symbol, symsError);
   }
}
```

The function where the `processSymbol()` compiled how I thought it should is this:

```
void processInsertSymbolData(ifstream & inFile, BST & symTable){
string symbol, value, rFlag, fourCharSymbol;
symsErrorCode symsError;
while(inFile >> symbol >> value >> rFlag){
    symsError = NO_ERROR;
    processSymbol(symbol, symsError);
    if(symsError == NO_ERROR)
    {
        fourCharSymbol = createFourCharSymbol(symbol);
        processValue(value, symsError);
        if(symsError == NO_ERROR)
        {
            processRFlag(rFlag, symsError);
            if(symsError == NO_ERROR)
            {
                insertIntoSymTable(symsError, fourCharSymbol, value, rFlag, symTable);
            }
        }
    }
    errorOutput( symsError, symbol, fourCharSymbol, value);
}
return;
}
```

Here is the `processSymbol(const string symbol, symsErrorCode symsError)` function

```
void processSymbol(const string symbol, symsErrorCode symsError){
if(symbol.length() > 10)
{
    symsError = LENGTH;
}
else if(!isalpha(symbol[0]))
{
    symsError = START_CHAR;
}
else
{
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i < symbol.length(); i++)
    {
        if( !isalnum(symbol[i]) && symbol[i] != '_' )
        {
            symsError = INVALID_CHAR;
        }
    }
}
return;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is any difference between the two cases. There is something else going on which you have not shown here. Can you show all the overload declarations of `processSymbol(const string, enumDataType)` ?

Comment: Can you also provide the processSymbol function? Also as an off-topic suggestion, I feel you are declaring using std, which is a bad practice. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @Mahesh I have added the other overloaded deceleration it could be to the error section.

Comment: @shunyo I have added the processSymbol function and yes I am declaring using std::cout, std::string, std::endl.

Comment: You have another declaration of `processSymbol` somewhere. The compiler thinks you are passing `std::string&` because you are doing exactly this, but it's normal and expected, don't worry about it. Find and kill or fix the other declaration of `processSymbol`.

Comment: The error shows two versions of processSymbol().  They have nearly identical signatures.  Get rid of one of them.

Comment: Thanks to n.m. and Brian beuning, I realized the issue was my prototype was `processSymbol(const string, enumDataType &)` but in my decleration I was missing a &: `processSymbol(const string, enumDataType ).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can't tell the difference between the two declarations of processSymbol that you are trying to call.  I would suggest using a pointer (*) instead of & for the enum.  That will make it clear to the compiler which version of the function you are intending to call.

```
processSymbol(const string symbol, symsErrorCode* symsError) ...
```

Comment: Instead of adding the possibility of null pointer errors, it might be more prudent to rename one of the functions and keep their signatures intact. Furthermore, there is little point to passing enums (and other small types) by reference, unless you need to edit them in place (which you can't on enums). At best, it's not slower, at worst, it's harder to read and runs slower.